# SQL trigger to add new records to a table with the same structure when an insertion is made

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create SQL trigger which adds a new record to the same table where an insertion is made through a web page. I am not exactly sure how to implement it but I tried the following query

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[trgI_DealsDoneInserRecord]
on [dbo].[Terms]
after insert 
As    
  Insert into DealsDone                
        (Company,Grade,Term,Pipeline,[Index],Volume,Price,[Type],CounterParty,
               TermID,GradeID,CPID,Locked,Product)
  VALUES 
        (SELECT Company,Grade,Term,Pipeline,[Index],Volume,Price,[Type],CounterParty,
           TermID,GradeID,CPID,Locked,Product FROM inserted)

END
```

The above query threw an error in the `SELECT` statement in `VALUES`.

**May I know a way to implement this?**

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. It should look like `INSERT INTO Table (col1,col2,...,coln) SELECT col1,col2,...,coln FROM inserted`

Comment: The title of the question says "insert into same table" yet the trigger definition shows a different table. Which is it? Or did you mean a different table having the same structure? If so, will it always have the same structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[trgI_DealsDoneInserRecord]
ON [dbo].[Terms]
AFTER INSERT 
As    
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO DealsDone                
        (Company,Grade,Term,Pipeline,[Index],Volume,Price,[Type],CounterParty,
               TermID,GradeID,CPID,Locked,Product)
  SELECT Company,Grade,Term,Pipeline,[Index],Volume,Price,[Type],CounterParty,
           TermID,GradeID,CPID,Locked,Product FROM inserted
END
```

Comment: Tried this with [ but it says Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

Comment: @Dev you had just forgot some square brackets. Now it should work.

Comment: Oh yeah I missed BEGIN at the top

Answer (score 1):

While I generally advocate *against* using `SELECT *`, in this case it seems like a benefit:

- By not specifying the fields you can automatically account for changes in the tables without having to update this trigger if you add or remove or even rename fields.
- This will help you catch errors in schema updates if one of the tables is updated but the other one isn't and the structure is then different. If that happens, the INSERT operation will fail and you don't have to worry about cleaning up bad data.

So use this:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgI_DealsDoneInserRecord]
ON [dbo].[Terms]
AFTER INSERT
AS
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT INTO [DealsDone]
      SELECT *
      FROM inserted;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an syntax issue, and also you are missing BEGIN

The basic syntax is

```
INSERT INTO table2  (column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;
```

So try this

```
    CREATE trigger [dbo].[trgI_DealsDoneInserRecord]
    on [dbo].[Terms]
    after insert 
    As
   BEGIN
       Insert into DealsDone                
          (Company,Grade,Term,Pipeline,[Index],Volume,Price,[Type],CounterParty,
                  TermID,GradeID,CPID,Locked,Product)
       SELECT Company,Grade,Term,Pipeline,[Index],Volume,Price,[Type],CounterParty,
                  TermID,GradeID,CPID,Locked,Product 
        FROM inserted
    END
```

Refer:- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I think some one edited my question and removed and I found it was edited by you.Please go back and check and thanks for letting me know my syntax was wrong